# Rendering custom opengl in qt5's qtquick 2.0

Tags: qt, opengl, qt-quick, qt5

I'm looking for a way to render my custom opengl calls inside a qtquick 2.0 item. To give you some context: I have a C++ 3d engine that uses opengl for rendering. The goal is to have it rendering inside a qtquick 2.0 UI.

What I found out is that pre qt 5.0 (qtquick 2.0) you would use a QtGlWidget and embed that into the QDeclarativeView. Another way I found would be to use a QtDeclarativeItem and override the void QDeclarativeItem::paint(QPainter *p, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *o, QWidget *w) method.

As I understand it this is not possible anymore as QtQuick 2.0 uses a new renderer which is based on OpenGl. It is therefore as it seems not as easy as overriding a paint method.

Does anybody know how I would go about implementing a QQuickItem that allows rendering of my opengl calls?

Answer (score 8):

You can do one of two things. Either render your content into a texture or render in the OpenGL context of the scene graph by hooking using the `QQuickWindow::beforeRendering` or `QQuickWindow::afterRendering` signals.

An example on how to use FBO and texture can be found here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html

An example on how to render directly to the OpenGL context of the scene graph can be found here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html

Comment: FBO (for Qt 5.2): http://qt.apidoc.info/5.2.0/qtquick/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html
Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML (for Qt 5): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html

Answer (score 3):

In your 3D engine, render into a texture and in your `QQuickItem` use `QSGSimpleTextureNode` to show the rendering results. QtQuick maintains it's own GL state, which you could otherwise mess up, that's why it is recommended to use only the QSG* classes to show custom content. Basically, plain QtQuick is a tool for rendering rectangles, not 3D content generally.

(Lame) example:

```
QScopedPointer<QSGTexture> texture_;

QSGNode* MyItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode* node, UpdatePaintNodeData*)
{
  if (width() <= 0 || height() <= 0)
  {
    texture_.reset();

    delete node;
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    if (!node)
    {
      node = new QSGSimpleTextureNode;

      static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode*>(node)
        ->setFiltering(QSGTexture::Nearest);
    }
    // else do nothing

    static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode*>(node)->setRect(boundingRect());

    getTheTextureFrom3DEngine(texture_);

    Q_ASSERT(texture_);
    static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode*>(node)->setTexture(texture_.data());

    return node;
  }
}
```

You also need to instantiate a Timer to update the contents. You can do this from within the QQuickItem.